# SQL issues in JOIN statement

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have these 4 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `football_league` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `league` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `country` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `code` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `football_goals` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `match` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `team` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `goals` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `time` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `match` (`match`),
  KEY `team` (`team`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `football_matches` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pcode` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `time` time NOT NULL,
  `team_1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `team_2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `minutes` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `remarks` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `pcode` (`pcode`),
  KEY `team_1` (`team_1`),
  KEY `team_2` (`team_2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;




CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `football_teams` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pcode` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `shortname` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `played` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `won` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `draw` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lost` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `points` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `previous_results` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `remarks` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `pcode` (`pcode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;



--
-- Constraints for table `football_goals`
--
ALTER TABLE `football_goals`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `football_goals_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`match`) REFERENCES `football_matches` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `football_goals_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`team`) REFERENCES `football_teams` (`id`);

--
-- Constraints for table `football_matches`
--
ALTER TABLE `football_matches`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `football_matches_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`pcode`) REFERENCES `football_league` (`code`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `football_matches_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`team_1`) REFERENCES `football_teams` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `football_matches_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`team_2`) REFERENCES `football_teams` (`id`);

--
-- Constraints for table `football_teams`
--
ALTER TABLE `football_teams`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `football_teams_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`pcode`) REFERENCES `football_league` (`code`);



INSERT INTO `football_league` (`id`, `league`, `country`, `code`) VALUES
(1, 'International', 'International', 'L001'),
(2, 'English Premier League', 'English', 'L002'),
(3, 'Scottish Premier League', 'Scotland', 'L003');


INSERT INTO `football_matches` (`id`, `pcode`, `date`, `time`, `team_1`, `team_2`, `minutes`, `status`, `remarks`) VALUES
(1, 'L001', '2015-07-06', '18:45:00', 1, 2, 0, 'running', '18:00'),
(2, 'L002', '2015-07-02', '18:00:00', 7, 8, 0, 'FT', ''),
(3, 'L001', '2015-07-06', '18:45:00', 1, 2, 22, 'running', '');



INSERT INTO `football_teams` (`id`, `pcode`, `name`, `shortname`, `played`, `won`, `draw`, `lost`, `points`, `previous_results`, `remarks`) VALUES
(1, 'L002', 'Arsenal', 'arsenal', 50, 30, 10, 10, 70, 'WWLLD', ''),
(2, 'L002', 'Chelsea', 'chelsea', 50, 20, 10, 20, 50, 'LLWWW', ''),
(6, 'L002', 'Manchester City', 'manchester', 30, 20, 3, 7, 60, 'WWWWW', ''),
(7, 'L001', 'England', 'england', 50, 20, 13, 17, 53, 'WLWLL', ''),
(8, 'L001', 'Brazil', 'brazil', 30, 22, 2, 6, 46, 'WLLWW', ''),
(9, 'L001', 'France', 'france', 36, 18, 10, 8, 46, 'LLLWW', '');


INSERT INTO `football_goals` (`id`, `match`, `team`, `goals`, `time`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 1, '2015-07-06 14:36:00'),
(2, 1, 2, 1, '2015-07-06 12:28:00'),
(3, 2, 7, 1, '2015-07-06 14:39:00'),
(4, 2, 8, 1, '2015-07-06 12:28:00'),
(6, 1, 1, 1, '2015-07-06 08:33:00');
```

I want to write a SQL statement, which will show all the matches with score by particular league and date. I have tried to write the below SQL:

```
SELECT 
football_league.code, football_matches.id,
football_league.league, football_league.country, 
football_matches.date, football_matches.time as match_time, 
football_matches.team_1, ft_1.name as name_a, 
ft_1.shortname as short_a,
football_matches.team_2, ft_2.name as name_b, 
ft_2.shortname as short_b, 
football_matches.minutes, football_matches.status, football_matches.remarks,
sum(fg_1.goals) as score_a,
sum(fg_2.goals) as score_b

FROM football_matches
INNER JOIN football_teams as ft_1 
ON ft_1.id = football_matches.team_1
INNER JOIN football_teams as ft_2 
ON ft_2.id = football_matches.team_2

INNER JOIN football_league 
ON football_league.code = football_matches.pcode

LEFT JOIN football_goals as fg_1 
ON `fg_1`.`match` = football_matches.id AND `fg_1`.`team` = ft_1.id

LEFT JOIN football_goals as fg_2 
ON `fg_2`.`match` = football_matches.id  AND `fg_2`.`team` = ft_2.id

WHERE 
football_league.code = 'L001' 
AND
football_matches.date = '2015-07-06'
```

My problem is:

i) The score showing wrong, it should be 2-1, instead it's showing 2-2

ii) Second problem is I also need to show other matches also, where no team scored a goal, which is not showing, I tried with LEFT JOIN, but it still not showing other matches.

Comment: Post `football_league` table structure and data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following:

```
SELECT 
football_league.code, football_matches.id,
football_league.league, football_league.country, 
football_matches.date, football_matches.time as match_time, 
football_matches.team_1, ft_1.name as name_a, 
ft_1.shortname as short_a,
football_matches.team_2, ft_2.name as name_b, 
ft_2.shortname as short_b, 
football_matches.minutes, football_matches.status, football_matches.remarks,
(SELECT sum(goals) FROM football_goals WHERE `match` = football_matches.id AND `team` = ft_1.id) as 'score1',
(SELECT sum(goals) FROM football_goals WHERE `match` = football_matches.id AND `team` = ft_2.id) as 'score2'

FROM football_matches
INNER JOIN football_teams as ft_1 
ON ft_1.id = football_matches.team_1
INNER JOIN football_teams as ft_2 
ON ft_2.id = football_matches.team_2

INNER JOIN football_league 
ON football_league.code = football_matches.pcode

LEFT JOIN football_goals as fg_1 
ON `fg_1`.`match` = football_matches.id AND `fg_1`.`team` = ft_1.id

LEFT JOIN football_goals as fg_2 
ON `fg_2`.`match` = football_matches.id  AND `fg_2`.`team` = ft_2.id

WHERE 
football_league.code = 'L001' 
AND
football_matches.date = '2015-07-06'
GROUP BY football_matches.id
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks it works! But, can you let me is there are any way to do this without using nested sql? Thanks again!

Comment: Hi! I don't see how to do it without nested SQL right now. What could improved is you don't need left joins now (forgot to remove them). And since nested SQL search based on foreign keys it should be indexed search and shouldn't break performance much.